# How EXISTS works in the oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

Beginner of Oracle SQL, I have some confusions about `EXISTS`. Here is an example:

```
 SELECT PORT_ID
 FROM PORTS P1
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM SHIPS S1
 WHERE P1.PORT_ID = S1.HOME_PORT_ID);
```

Let's say there are some rows that shares the same value in columna `PORT_ID` and `HOME_PORT_ID`, which means the subquery in the `WHERE` clause return `TRUE`.

I am wondering which rows will be selected. Do all `PORT_ID` in the table `PORTS` will be selected or just `PORT_ID` that are equal to `HOME_PORT_ID` will be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the rows in `ports` that have a matching line in `ships` (using predicate `P1.PORT_ID = S1.HOME_PORT_ID`) will show up.

That means that if there is no row in `ships` with the same `port_id`, the rows of `ports` will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

All PORT_ID values from PORTS whose values exist in the HOME_PORT_ID column of the SHIPS table are returned.

Your query, which queries SHIPS once for every row in PORTS, can be rewritten more efficiently as:

```
SELECT PORT_ID
FROM PORTS
WHERE PORT_ID IN
 (SELECT HOME_PORT_ID FROM SHIPS)
```

which only queries SHIPS once. But it can be rewritten even more efficiently as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PORT_ID
FROM PORTS
JOIN SHIPS ON PORT_ID = HOME_PORT_ID
```

which will can efficiently use the index on HOME_PORT_ID if one exists, or if not do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOME_PORT_ID
FROM SHIPS
JOIN PORTS ON PORT_ID = HOME_PORT_ID
```

which will use the primary key index of PORT (which will exist)